# Why does the bottom portion print out of order?

Tags: python

First time here, I'm working on starting my Software Development & Programming Cert. through the Berkeley Extension program and my uncle helped me get a few programming books to get a bit of a headstart before I can officially register and start.

I decided to expand on one of the examples provided in the book by seeing if I could create the same results they do through a different route.

Long story short when I run the top line of the commented out portion it prints in order(0 1 2). However, when I run the uncommented second portion it prints 0 2 1. Was hoping someone could clarify why for me, my first inclination is that it has something to do with the `unconfirmed_users.remove(user)` though thats just a guess from a novice ^^;

```
    unconfirmed_users = [ 'anna', 'bryce', 'carmina',]
confirmed_users = []

#while unconfirmed_users:
    #confirmed_user = unconfirmed_users.pop()
    #print("Confirming user: " + confirmed_user.title())
    #confirmed_users.append(confirmed_user)
#print("\nThe following users have been confirmed: ")
#for users in confirmed_users:
    #print(users.title())


while unconfirmed_users:
    for user in unconfirmed_users:
        print("Confimring User: " + user.title())
        unconfirmed_users.remove(user)
        confirmed_users.append(user)
print("\nThe following users have been confirmed: ")
for users in confirmed_users:
    print(users.title())
```

Comment: You shouldn't iterate through a collection with a for each construct and remove elements at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing may seem sensible, but Python translates your `for` loop into something like this:

```
i = 0
while i < len(unconfirmed_users):
    user = unconfirmed_users[i]
    # ...
    unconfirmed_users.remove(user)
    i += 1
```

So behind the scenes, Python is reading the first element of the list (`'anna'`), then removing it, then moving to the second element *of the modified list* (`'carmina'`, because `'anna'` was removed and now `'bryce'` is the first element).  Your code would print `'anna'` and `'carmina'` only if not for the too-clever-by-half `while` loop on the outside, which repeats this iteration and picks up the element you skipped the second time through the `for` loop.

As a side note, you probably shouldn't modify a list while you are iterating over it unless you have a really good reason to do so.  Check out [the definition of the `for` statement](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) in the documentation, especially the last paragraph at the end describing exactly this situation.

Comment: Nice link.  I was looking for that. :-)

Comment: Thanks! this is _exactly_ what I was looking for! and the last paragraph definitely helped explain it (in particular the internal counter bit).

Answer (score 0):

list.pop() by default returns and deletes the last value in a list, meanwhile your for loop is iterating from the start. Hence the 2 versions of code creating mirrored results.

Answer (score 0):

It appears in the first block of code that is commented, you are iterating thru the unconfirmed_users by using pop().  pop() pops off from the end of the list as in unconfirmed_users[-1].  Where in the second code block you use the for loop which starts from the beginning of the list as in unconfirmed_users[0].